# L0 norm compressed sensing vs L1 norm compressed sensing

Tags: signal-analysis, compressed-sensing

Suppose we have an very efficient way to perform L0 norm compressed vs L1 norm compressed sensing. Specifically: L0 norm compressed sensing is:

$$\eqalign{
  & \min \quad {x^T}Qx + {b^T}x + \mu {\left\| x \right\|_0}  \cr 
  & s.t:\quad Ax \le b \cr} $$

while L1 norm compressed sensing:

$$\eqalign{
  & \min \quad {x^T}Qx + {b^T}x + \mu {\left\| x \right\|_1}  \cr 
  & s.t:\quad Ax \le b \cr} $$

Should we almost always use the L0 norm formulation? Is there any paper discussing the benefit of L0 (disregard the computational perspectives) over L1 norm compressed sensing?

**Edit**: The actual application we are interested in is about avoiding overfitting formulated below. For example $x$ is a very long feature vector (say length 1000), how ever we only 100 data, i.e., ${E_{feature}}$ is 100 by 1000, and ${E_{input}}$ is 100 by 1. The question we are interested in is whether the L0 norm formulation (if can be computed practically) can offer significant advantage over the L1 norm formulation.

$$\eqalign{
  & \min \quad \left\| {{E_{feature}}x - {E_{input}}} \right\|_2^2 + \mu {\left\| x \right\|_{0,1}}  \cr 
  & s.t:\quad Ax \le b \cr} $$

Comment: "Should we almost always use the L0 norm formulation?" To accomplish what? Without that information, there is no answer.

Comment: Ehm... So the question is mostly, "disregard the computational complexity", what is the generally agreed benefit of L0 norm compressed sensing?

Comment: Minimizing the L0 norm minimizes the required number of "bits" into which a signal can be compressed and transmitted.

Comment: I see... I edited the question to actually emphasize the application (avoiding overfitting) we want to do... Would you like to offer additional insights from that perspective? Thank you.

Comment: Are you familiar with: "Iterative hard thresholding" --- that works provably under the "usual" RIP assumptions (and the word "hard" in there refers to the use of the $\ell_0$-quasi-norm)

Comment: @Suvrit  Thank you very much. I am actually not familiar with that. I would dig into that:) You could also post your answer so that I could accept it if you want :)

Comment: @Suvrit so does Hard Thresholding Pursuit or Orthogonal Matching Pursuit. But these are efficient ways to approximate the $\ell_0$ CS here, but do not detail why you should use them instead of $\ell_1$ (basis pursuit, btw)

Comment: Cross-posted: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/26530/4274